# How to iterate over an array column in PySpark while joining

Tags: pyspark

In PySpark, I have **dataframe_a** with:

```
+-----------+----------------------+
| str1      | array_of_str         |
+-----------+----------------------+
| John      | [mango, apple]       |
| Tom       | [mango, orange]      |
| Matteo    | [apple, banana]      |
```

and **dataframe_b** with

```
+-----------+----------------------+
| key       | value                |
+-----------+----------------------+
| mango     | 1                    |
| apple     | 2                    |
| orange    | 3                    |
```

and I want to create a new column of type Array `joined_result` that maps each element in `array_of_str` (*dataframe_a*) to its value in *dataframe_b*, such as:

```
+-----------+----------------------+----------------------------------+
| str1      | array_of_str         | joined_result                    |
+-----------+----------------------+----------------------------------+
| John      | [mango, apple]       | [1, 2]                           |
| Tom       | [mango, orange]      | [1, 3]                           |
| Matteo    | [apple, banana]      | [2]                              |
```

I'm not sure how to do it, I know I can use an udf with a lambda function but I don't manage to make it work :( Help!

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, ArrayType

# START EXTRACT OF CODE
ret = (df
  .select(['str1', 'array_of_str'])
  .withColumn('joined_result', F.udf(
     map(lambda x: ??????, ArrayType(StringType))
  )
)

return ret
# END EXTRACT OF CODE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer in your question:

```
lookup_list = map(lambda row: row.asDict(), dataframe_b.collect())
lookup_dict = {lookup['key']:lookup['value'] for lookup in lookup_list}

def mapper(keys):
  return [lookup_dict[key][0] for key in keys]

dataframe_a = dataframe_a.withColumn('joined_result', F.udf(mapper)("arr_of_str"))
```

It works as you want :-)

Comment: Such as 
```dataframe_a = dataframe_a.withColumn('joined_result', F.udf(mapper, dataframe_b)("arr_of_str"))```

Comment: You can not do that, because udf  run in one dataframe (in our case in dataframe_a). Also, the udf run in PVM (Python Virtual Machine) so you have to pass a Python object like dictionary, not a dataframe. You can suppose that the second dataframe is a lookup dataframe and it will not be extremely large. I don't know your case but this solution is working nice.

Comment: somehow I am getting the new column ```joined_result``` with array within array:
[[1],[2]]

Comment: I think I fix it, I added [0] in the `lookup_dict[key][0]` in the answer. Check it again and tell me :-)

Comment: Thanks for helping out :) I didn't work, it's still returning an array in an array but just the first character  =)